# Handler for several kinds of requests to modify a database in an Android app

Tags: java, android, database

I'm working on an Android app, and at one point I need to retrieve a request code in a callback method and perform some database operations depending on the request code. It started out ok when there were just 2 request codes, but then I had a need to add two more, and I can't really find a good way to avoid a messy looking method.

This is the method right now

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    final Context applicationContext = getContext();

    DevLog.v(TAG, "onActivityResult()   requestCode="+requestCode+"   resultCode="+resultCode+"   data="+data);

    if( (requestCode == ACTIVITY_REQUEST_ADD_SENDER ||
            requestCode == ACTIVITY_REQUEST_EDIT_SENDER ||
            requestCode == ACTIVITY_REQUEST_ADD_SOS_RECEIVER ||
            requestCode == ACTIVITY_REQUEST_EDIT_SOS_RECEIVER)
            && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && data != null
            && applicationContext != null ){

        final String number = getNumberFromContactResultIntent(data);
        if (number != null) {
            AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    switch (requestCode) {
                        case ACTIVITY_REQUEST_ADD_SENDER:
                            AppDatabase.db(applicationContext).getSenderDao().insert(new Sender(number));
                            break;
                        case ACTIVITY_REQUEST_EDIT_SENDER:
                            if (mEditSender != null) {
                                mEditSender.number = number;
                                AppDatabase.db(applicationContext).getSenderDao().update(mEditSender);
                            }
                            break;
                        case ACTIVITY_REQUEST_ADD_SOS_RECEIVER:
                            AppDatabase.db(applicationContext).getSosReceiverDao().insert(new SosReceiver(number));
                            break;
                        case ACTIVITY_REQUEST_EDIT_SOS_RECEIVER:
                            if (mEditSosReceiver != null ) {
                                mEditSosReceiver.number = number;
                                AppDatabase.db(applicationContext).getSosReceiverDao().update( mEditSosReceiver );
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
    else
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

What bugs me the most is the repeated check of the `requestCode` parameter. First I need to check if it's **any** of four values (the `if`), and then I have to perform different operations depending on **exactly** which of those four values it is (the `switch`).

If I remove the `if( (requestCode ...` part and move the `switch` statement out from the `AsyncTask`, I would still need to perform the other checks (`resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null ...` etc), **AND** I would have to create one `AsyncTask` in each `case`, so I'd basically end up with even more redundant code than there already is.

I would also need to move the

```
getNumberFromContactResultIntent(data)
```

call, since it only makes sense for these four request codes and shouldn't be called on any other request codes.

I considered putting the four request codes into an array (they are `static final int`) and call it something like `REQUEST_CODE_GROUP_ADD_OR_EDIT` and perform

```
Arrays.binarySearch(REQUEST_CODE_GROUP_ADD_OR_EDIT, requestCode)
```

on it, which would at least reduce the `if` statement slightly. But it seems a bit silly to turn four simple and efficient `==` checks into a much more complex operation. It's highly unlikely I'll need to add more similar request codes in the future, and if I do it will most certainly only be a limited number of them (2-4).

Is there a neat way to simplify something like this, where one needs to combine first checking for **any** of a limited set of values, perform some operations that is common to all of them, and then perform some operations that are **specific for each** value?

Comment: It would be probably too little for a full feature answer in this site but I hope that this could help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern (It helped me when I had similar situation in my own projects)

Comment: In addition, don't hesitate to extract `switch` cases or `if` branches into separate methods or classes. Software always have a tendency to grow fast. Sooner or later you will end up with a requirement to add new cases. It would be better to maintain readability, flexibility and scalability since very beginning!

Comment: I had a look at the pattern, and I guess it sort of does what I need, but I think the increased complexity is not worth it in this case just to avoid this one "ugly" method. I also considered breaking out the switch or if, and while it could be an improvement, in a sense it would just move the problem elsewhere. I'm still interested in ways to improve these kinds of scenarios, but I actually ended up refactoring my Sender and SosReceiver classes into one Contact class, so the problem sort of solved itself ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could define an abstract class that holds a request code and a command.
Then for each code, create a concrete subclass that hold that code and command associated with that code. Then you pass an instance of that concrete subclass, do your null checks, and call the command.